# Set or configure timeout of endpoints in cloud endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Is there a way to set or configure the timeout of endpoints in Cloud Endpoints? I believe the default is 60 but is there a way to change this?

Note: this is a Java project.

Comment: Does this [SO answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61600086/10190802) answer your question?

Comment: @Darwin Somewhat, I am still unsure how to set this deadline in my endpoints project. Which file do I add the `deadline` property in?

Comment: you can add it in the yaml file just like this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-quickstart/blob/master/openapi.yaml) then you can add the `x-google-backend:` key after  `operationId` in line 28.

Comment: This is another [sample yaml file](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/secure-traffic-gcloud#creating_an_api_config) that uses the `x-google-backend` to set `deadline`.  Note that the link is for `API Gateway` service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you can add the `deadline` property to configure timeouts in the yaml file just like this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-quickstart/blob/master/openapi.yaml) then you can add the `x-google-backend`: key after `operationId` in line 28

This is another [sample yaml](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/secure-traffic-gcloud#creating_an_api_config) file that uses the `x-google-backend` to set `deadline`. Note that the link is for **API Gateway** service.

Comment: My endpoints application actually does not have an `openapi.yaml` file. It still works all the same. Also I forgot to mention it is a Java project. Does that change things? Is there a link to the documentation of the `deadline` property?

Comment: This is the only link that I could find on [`deadline` property](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#deadline). Please note that `deadline` property is a new feature in **ESPv2** and not supported by **ESP**